# Nested ellipse diagram with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to create something like the following:

[image]

[image]

However, my current attempt, the formatting is incorrect, I cannot seem to make the oval/ellipse shape and the text doesn't fit inside of the circles.

How can I generate something similar to the below?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{set/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,align=center}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,transform shape]
\node[set,fill=blue!25,text width=3cm,label={[below=85pt of rea] Some text here }] 
  (nat) at (0,-0.4)  (rea) {};
\node[set,fill=blue!50,text width=2cm,label={[below=55pt of int] Some more text here}] 
  (int) at (0,-0.2)  {};
\node[set,fill=blue!75,text width=1cm] (nat) at (0,0) {Even more text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following could serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{set/.style={draw,ellipse,inner sep=0pt,align=left, anchor=east}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[set,fill=blue!25,text width=8cm, minimum height=4cm] 
  (rea) {Artificial\\ Intelligence};
\node[set,fill=blue!50,text width=5cm, minimum height=3cm] 
 (int)  {Machine\\ Learning};
\node[set,fill=blue!75,text width=3cm, minimum height=2cm] 
  (nat)  {Deep\\ Learning};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid](16,10)
        \psellipse[fillcolor=red!20](8,5)(8,5)
        \psellipse[fillcolor=green!20](10,5)(6,4.25)
        \psellipse[fillcolor=blue!20](12,5)(4,3.25)
        \rput(2.5,5){\parbox{4cm}{\huge \textbf{\color{blue} Artificial Stupidity}}}
        \rput(6.5,5){\parbox{4cm}{\huge \textbf{\color{red} Deep Sleeping}}}
        \rput(12,5){\parbox{6cm}{\huge \textbf{Money Oriented Programming}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The contents are trivial!

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of patience it is possibile to built the diagrams using a tool that I like very much for your flexibility and creativity: [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).
I add my proposal here:

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
  \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8pt,y=0.8pt,yscale=-.9,xscale=.9,scale=.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,479); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 479

%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp06805705892692715] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 70; green, 63; blue, 207 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (5.5,235.57) .. controls (5.5,117.16) and (178.06,21.18) .. (390.92,21.18) .. controls (603.78,21.18) and (776.34,117.16) .. (776.34,235.57) .. controls (776.34,353.98) and (603.78,449.97) .. (390.92,449.97) .. controls (178.06,449.97) and (5.5,353.98) .. (5.5,235.57) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp7951435784625336] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 83; green, 46; blue, 160 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (5.5,235.57) .. controls (5.5,159.2) and (125.67,97.29) .. (273.92,97.29) .. controls (422.16,97.29) and (542.34,159.2) .. (542.34,235.57) .. controls (542.34,311.94) and (422.16,373.86) .. (273.92,373.86) .. controls (125.67,373.86) and (5.5,311.94) .. (5.5,235.57) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp019862855634055432] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 56; green, 40; blue, 146 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (5.5,235.57) .. controls (5.5,188.63) and (72.1,150.57) .. (154.25,150.57) .. controls (236.4,150.57) and (303,188.63) .. (303,235.57) .. controls (303,282.52) and (236.4,320.57) .. (154.25,320.57) .. controls (72.1,320.57) and (5.5,282.52) .. (5.5,235.57) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (89,162) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{100.0756pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.97,0.91,0.11}{{\sffamily\textbf{{\large Deep Learning}}}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (40,192) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 231; blue, 28 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{161.34632000000002pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\sffamily The subset of the machine learning}\\{ \sffamily composed of alghorithms that permit}\\{ \sffamily software to train itself }
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (295,142) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{122.15180000000001pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{{\sffamily \textbf{{\large Machine Learning}}}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (300,176) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 231; blue, 28 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{122.11644000000001pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{ \sffamily\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{A subset of AI that includes}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{dfoidfiodfiodnfdin}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{soidiofbsigbsiob}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{sdigiosdhgiosdfhgi}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{sdpogjopsdjgopsjgopsj}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{spgspgpsopfngofpsng}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (532,145) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{140.19084pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.89,0.99}{{\sffamily\textbf{{\large Artificial intelligence}}}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (558,175) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 231; blue, 28 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{110.53536pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{ \sffamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{Any tecnique that }}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{enables sdègjsdgj}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{sdojgodsjgopjvdmmgsmg}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{sdpogjsopjgojgosjg}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{dgjogjopsdjgopdsfjgjo}}\\{ \sffamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{dgjsdopgjosdjgodpsjgopsj}}\\{ \sffamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{sdgjodpsjgdopjog}}\\{ \sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.85,0.91,0.97}{sdgsdogjodghosh}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Your caption.}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]